# Full screen center cropped slideshow using css in safari

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem getting the css working for a full screen slider. It works perfectly fine on Chrome, safari for iPad and android browser, but I'm getting a blank background on safari for Mac.

Basically I'm using owl carousel to create a full screen touch enabled slideshow. The html:

```
<body>
<div id="slides" class="owl-carousel">
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(img1.jpg);"><img src="img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(img2.jpg);"><img src="img2.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(img3.jpg);"><img src="img3.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

css:

```
    #slides {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}


#slides .owl-item .item{
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slides .owl-item .item img{
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
```

On safari, the first image shows up fine, and correct. When changing to the second or 3rd image, the background is blank. If I disable 'background-attachment: fixed;' it shows up, but not positioned properly.

Here's the site: [www.samuiweddings.com](http://samuiweddings.com)

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, using background-color instead of background-image works just fine. It's only the images which disappear.